# Solving equations of the form $y(x) f(x) =0$

Tags: distribution-theory

When speaking with my advisor recently, we were led in the course of a physics problem to an equation of the form $$y(x) \ f(x) = 0$$ with $f(x)$ known and $y(x)$ unknown. My immediate instinct was to conclude that $y(x) = 0$ for all $x$. Clearly, this must be the right conclusion if there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=0$.

However, my advisor claims that a more general solution for any $f(x)$ is $$y(x) = \sum_{n=1}^m c_n \delta(x-x_n) $$ where the $c_n$ are arbitrary, $\delta()$ is the dirac distribution, and the $x_n$ satisfy $f(x_n) = 0$.

Intuitively, I understand why this is reasonable, but can it be justified rigorously? Is there any reason to prefer this solution over my instinctual one? The case of $f(x) =0$ seems particularly troublesome for this idea.

Follow-up: Thanks to Martin for providing a counter-example for arbitrary $f$. Does the claim hold if we require that $f$ is continuous and vanishes at a finite number of points?

Comment: Is there any continuity imposing on $f$ or $y$?

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends on what $f$ looks like. Your advisor's suggestion seems to imply that the thinks that $f=0$ on a finite number of points $x_1,\ldots,x_m$. But unless you specify this as a condition, it is not necessarily the case: consider for instance
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2,&\mbox{ if }x\geq0 \\ 0,&\mbox{ if } x<0  \end{cases}
$$
and $y(x)=f(-x)$. Then both $f$ and $y$ are differentiable, $y(x)f(x)=0$ for all $x$, and $y$ is not of the form you mention.

Comment: Excellent counter example, thank you! As a follow up, what if we do impose the restriction that $f$ is continuous and is $0$ at a finite number of points. Then does the claim hold?

Comment: @Kevin: You have to decide what kind of thing $y$ is supposed to be before the problem is well-posed. e.g. the professors solution isn't a solution at all if $y$ is supposed to be a *function*. However, if $y$ *is* supposed to be a function, then you can give $y$ any value you like at the points where $f$ vanishes (however, they have to be actual real values, like $f(x_n) = 42$). If $y$ is a function modulo negligible functions, then you get the same solution no matter what value you assign to $y$ at those finitely many points (in particular, all solutions are equivalent to $y=0$)

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, I agree. I had been thinking of $y$ as a function, so the appearance of Dirac deltas was a shock to me. However, I guess that if we specify the $y$ may be a distribution in the Schwartz Space(??) from the beginning then this makes more sense.

Comment: That's is an identity:
${\large%
x^{2}\Theta\left(-x\right)\ x^{2}\Theta\left(x\right) = 0}$.

Comment: The solution of ${\large\quad{\rm y}\left(x\right){\rm f}\left(x\right) = 0\quad}$ is ${\large\quad{\rm y}\left(x\right) = \Theta\left(x\right){\rm g}\left(x\right)}$ where ${\large{\rm g}}$ is an "arbitrary" function. ${\large{\rm f}\left(x\right) = 0}$ has infinite roots: All of them belong to ${\large\left(-\infty, 0\right\rbrack}$.

Comment: There is no issue with the $y$ proposed by the supervisor. It is exactly what $y$ would be if $f$ is zero at a finite number of points. And it is a function alright; not continuous, of course.

Comment: @MartinArgerami So we would say that both $y(x)=0$ and $y(x) = \sum_{n=1}^m c_n \delta(x-x_n)$ are solutions, along with infinitely many other constructions where $y$ is zero almost everywhere and $y(x_n) = c_n$ with the c's arbitrary, again?

Comment: The proper thing to say is that $y$ can be non-zero wherever $f$ is zero. If $f$ is zero at finitely many points, then $y$ is a linear combination of deltas (including $0$). If the set of zero points of $f$ is bigger, then $y$ can be of many different forms. If you think about my example above, for that $f$ $y$ can be any function that is zero on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example: $\displaystyle{{\rm y}'\left(x\right) = 0}$ with
$\displaystyle{{\rm y}\left(0\right) = y_{0}}$. It has the obvious solution
$\displaystyle{{\rm y}\left(x\right) = y_{0},\ \forall\ x}$. Let's assume we insist ($~\small\it\mbox{it's like killing an cockroach with a gun machine}~$) to use a Fourier transform to solve this equation:

\begin{equation}
{\rm y}\left(x\right)
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{{\rm d}k \over 2\pi}\,\tilde{\rm y}\left(k\right)
{\rm e}^{{\rm i}kx}.
\quad
\mbox{We get}\phantom{A}
{\rm i}k\tilde{\rm y}\left(k\right)
=
0
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\tilde{\rm y}\left(k\right) = A\,\delta\left(k\right)
\qquad\qquad\left(\Large\tt\mbox{I}\right)
\end{equation}

where $A$ is a constant. Then
$$
{\rm y}\left(x\right)
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{{\rm d}k \over 2\pi}\,
A\,\delta\left(k\right){\rm e}^{{\rm i}kx}
=
{A \over 2\pi}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
{\rm y}\left(0\right) = y_{0} = {A \over 2\pi}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
{\rm y}\left(x\right) = y_{0}\,,\ \forall\ x
$$

If you set $\tilde{\rm y}\left(k\right) = 0$ in step
$\left(\Large\tt\mbox{I}\right)$, you get the wrong result ${\rm y}\left(x\right) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, I agree that we can get the wrong result if we are too hasty. So, I pose as a question, how do we know that setting $\widetilde{y}$ to $0$ in (I) is an incorrect step? Is it because, as Hurkyl suggests, we must specify what kind of 'thing' $y$ must be beforehand? In your example, we must have that $\widetilde{y}$ lives in the dual of the Schwartz Space because you have assumed that it has a well-defined Fourier Transform and thus may be zero almost everywhere, but nonzero at finitely many points.

Comment: @KevinDriscoll I agree with your comment.